# Font size doubles unexpectedly in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

The figure font size doubled unexpectedly between knits. Restarting R did not fix the issue. I ended up decreasing font size by 50% to fix the problem. Has this happened to anyone else? My theme is shown below.

```
style <- theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 30),
               plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 30),
               axis.title = element_text(size = 25, face="italic"),
               axis.text = element_text(size = 25),
               legend.text = element_text(size = 25),
               legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 25),
               legend.position = "bottom",
               panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey88"),
               axis.ticks = element_line(color=NA),
               axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)),
               axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it changes between knits, maybe you were zoomed in on your web browser and didn't know it. it also might depend on your knit R chunks. if you can't replicate the issue, it might just be a random issue.